# beginner's python class constructor takes no argumens

Tags: python, class

I'm just learning python, and seem to be making a trivial mistake. With this code, the use of the constructor to Patterns gets and error.

"    cit_ref = Patterns( patstring, 3)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments"

```
import re

class Patterns:
    """A simple struct to hold our regex """
def __init__(self, pat, bodynumArg=2):
    self.pat = pat
    self.bodynum = bodynumArg
    self.reg = re.compile(self.pat, re.M+re.S)

patstring = r'<((us-)?references-cited)>(.*?)</\1>'
cit_ref = Patterns( patstring, 3)
```

Comment: Is this your actual indentation?  `__init__` is not indented to the correct level.

Comment: Barring indentation problems, I can't see anything wrong.  Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Yes, that is the real code. I didn't realize that the __init__ was expected to be indented. Still getting used to pythons use of indenting instead of {}  

Thanks

Comment: @fishtoprecords: If you were defining a class in Java or C++ or whatever you're used to, wouldn't you indent the methods inside the `{}`?

Comment: @aba, actually, no. I don't like indenting the outer level methods and member variables. I try to keep short line lengths and so I'm used to not indenting the first level. Just a personal quirk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to indent your `__init__` function so that it is under `class Patterns`. Like this:

```
import re

class Patterns:
    """A simple struct to hold our regex """
    def __init__(self, pat, bodynumArg=2):
        self.pat = pat
        self.bodynum = bodynumArg
        self.reg = re.compile(self.pat, re.M+re.S)

patstring = r'<((us-)?references-cited)>(.*?)</\1>'
cit_ref = Patterns( patstring, 3)
```

In Python, indents do basically the same thing that brackets/braces do in other languages- they delimit code, so you have to be careful with your indentation.

Comment: No wonder it looked right -- I just assumed OP was having trouble with SO markup as so many people do.  It's funny that a class without the docstring would have made the error much more obvious.

Comment: @mgilson Yeah, I started to do an edit but then realized that things before and after the `init` block were indented correctly with markdown.

Comment: I suppose that's why there are so many people around here who hold to the "Never edit code in a question" position :)

Comment: Thanks, I've mostly got cutting and pasting into SO from all my Java questions. This indent thing will take time to sink in.

Comment: @fishtoprecords It can seem odd at first, but then it starts being nice, IMO. Basically whenever you want to use `{}`, just indent another level instead, and you should be good to go.